# Creating expressions within Query Builder / Dataset Designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Looking at translating some access stuff I have written into vb.net using dataset designer, I am fairly new to dataset designer, lets say I have a calculated field in an access query:

```
Over Age 25: Year(Now())-Year([DOB])
```

How does this translate to data designer queries? What logic are they based on?  The functions seem to be  handled much differently than access, so, are the functions based on a different set of technologies?  What do I need to look over in order to understand how these functions should be implemented, such as DatePart() translating to the data designer rather than through using something like access query design?

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 0):

declare @DateOfBirth datetime;
set @DateOfBirth = '06/30/2001';
select DATEDIFF(YYYY, @DateOfBirth, getdate()) as AgeInYears;

The functions in Query Designer are T/SQL, not Visual Basic.  In Access, you can use standard VBA functions or your own in Queries.  If you are using SQL Server, in comparison, all that's available is the T/SQL functionality - VB.NET or your own functions aren't within scope.  You could create a VB.NET package and add it to the SQL Server instance, but that's a bit of a stretch if you're just getting into VB.NET.

Comment: I was given an example as far as splitting dates: `Dim CmdStr as string = “SELECT DATEPART(year, yourDateColumn) AS eYear FROM YourTable” ` Note that this is not via designer, I guess i will need to code it by hand...